# JS for visibility effect not working with addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, css

Skimmed through similar questions but didnt quite get the answer im looking for. I have an `<a>` that I want to be visible when hovering another `<a>`. I know my code is getting messy but still wanna know if this is doable. I tried with addeventlistener, which I thought would work, but it does absolutely nothing, is something missing from my js?

```js
document.getElementById("defaultlang").addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
document.getElementById("defaultlang").addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);

function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementById('secondlang').style.visibility = "visible";
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.getElementById('secondlang').style.visibilty = "hidden";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#headermenu li + li:before {
    content: "/";
    padding: 0px 11px 0px 0px;
    color: #abb8c3;
}

#secondlang {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ruflag {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: -2em;
  background: black;
  left: 400px;
  top: 20px;
}


header div span {
  position: relative;
}

.lang {
  position: relative;
  left: 460px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: -2em;
}

.lang:hover + .ruflag {
  visibility: visible;
}

header span p {
  display: inline;
  color: #164da8;
}

button a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 18px 40px;
  margin: -2em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-stretch: ultra-condensed;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

button a:hover {
  color: #e9b003;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

header {
  font-family: "Barlow Condensed",sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
  font-stretch: ultra-condensed;
}
ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 90px;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

ul li a {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
  color: #332826;
  font-stretch: ultra-condensed;
}

a:hover {
  color: #164da8;
}

.rutext {
  color: #b2a9a6;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}


.logo {
  width: 177px;
  height: 77px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.headerbox {
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}

.epoodnupp {
  height: 50px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #164da8;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 880px;

}

.heading2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.294rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Fixus</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fixus.css">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.googleapis.com">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fixusjs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="headerbox flex">
      <a class="lang" href="#" id="defaultlang">
        <span>
          <img src="https://fixus.ee/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/flags/et.png" alt="">
          <p>Eesti</p>
        </span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" title="Русский" class="ruflag hidden" id="secondlang">
        <span>
          <img src="https://fixus.ee/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/flags/ru.png" alt="">
          <p class="rutext">Русский</p>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What is expected outcome? I see the Estonian flag gets replace by a Russian flag. Not a good sign in these days

Comment: Hahhaha good one. Its just an project for school. Have to do a site based on an existing site, basically trying to copy it. And the site has 2 languages. Russian language box appears when you hover over the estonian one. That is all, I promise :D

Comment: The mouseout will not work because the secondlang is overlaying

Comment: it only looks like it here for some reason, when i open the entire thing in chrome it works fine, the hidden box appears next to it

Comment: I have Chrome. The Russian stays

Comment: i think its cuz i removed some HTML. Its built very badly tbh. Its fine tho, practice makes perfect

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with plains css

```
#defaultlang:hover ~ #secondlang {
    visibility: visible;
}

#secondlang {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

`~` selects all the siblings of #defaultlang. You can use `+` to select only the adjacent sibling.

Comment: Did you try? The mouseout will not work because the secondlang is overlaying

Comment: I did try it, there is no need for Javascript. Edit: I see what you mean, the second link has left: 400px which overlaps it over the first link.

Comment: this works yes, dont need visibility hidden, already have secondlang hidden by default. only needed the first part. thank you @RandomSlav

Comment: Please take OP's HTML and add your CSS. Just click edit and copy the snippet from OP

Comment: @caps i guess you want them to be centered and overlaping, so here is a simplified [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6pg8te0/)

Comment: well in the original its randomly placed it feels like (www.fixus.ee) so i think it doesnt matter where it appears, i think its bad if it is completely covering the original. I also got it to work so it wont dissapear if i try to hover over the russian language box so with that it would now be possible to change site language. Thank you tho! :)